# Change the order of the columns in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a Table with 5 Columns, (title, hash, story, source, time, url)...

I want that "url" is the first column... How can I do that - that the table look like

(url, title, hash, story, source, time)

Comment: `SELECT url, title, hash, story, source, time FROM ....`

Answer (score 1):

Use this query,

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CHANGE url url VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL FIRST;
or
ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY url VARCHAR(100) FIRST;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using phpMyAdmin? If so there's a button called "Move Columns" in the interface [image]

Comment: Perfect ;) Thanks!